# I want to add 100 years to the displayed wordpress dates

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm going to create a "future"-blogg (sort of a sci-fi-adventure in blog form) and want to display all dates +100 years. For instance a post published 2012-05-17 should display the date 2112-05-17.

First I thought I could just easily set the date to 2112-05-17, but it seems that wordpress can't handle dates higher than 2049.

So my next idea is to modify how the dates are displayed. I was thinking of modifying  get_the_date() in general-template.php, and make it return the later date.

But here my skills are not enough. I don't know anything about how to work with date values in php.

get_the_date() looks like this:

```
function get_the_date( $d = '' ) {
        global $post;
        $the_date = '';

        if ( '' == $d )
                $the_date .= mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_date);
        else
                $the_date .= mysql2date($d, $post->post_date);

        return apply_filters('get_the_date', $the_date, $d);
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify it? So it adds 100 years to the date before returning it?

Any input would be appriciated :)

Comment: `I don't know anything about how to work with date values in php` Time to read the manual and your PHP book, then.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might need to investigate date_modify and also strtotime

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mysql dates are of the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

```
function add100yr( $date="2011-03-04" ) {
    $timezone=date_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

    list($year, $month, $day) = split(':', $date); 
    $timestamp=mktime(0,0,0, $month, $day, $year);

    // 100 years, 365.25 days/yr, 24h/day, 60min/h, 60sec/min
    $seconds = 100 * 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $newdate =  date("Y-m-d", $timestamp+$seconds );
    // $newdate is now formatted YYYY-mm-dd
}
```

Now you can:

```
function get_the_date( $d = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $the_date = '';

    if ( '' == $d )
            $the_date .= mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), add100yr($post->post_date));
    else
            $the_date .= mysql2date($d, add100yr($post->post_date));

    return apply_filters('get_the_date', $the_date, $d);
}
```

Comment: `$minutes` is actually seconds so you have a misleading variable name. The rest of the function is cumbersome as well. Just use `strtotime()` on the string representation of the date.

Comment: Thanks mate, patched ;-) Also, strtotime() behaves slightly differently on some older version of php -- I've had some bad experience with clients who aren't running the latest and greatest

Comment: Here is a perfect example (posted today) of what I was talking about with strtotime() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656436/strtotime-weird-behaviour

Comment: The date in this question was not formatted in an ambiguous way. YYYY-MM-DD will not have these "strange" behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom field: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

You will have to enter the +100 year date for each post, but then you're not going to be relying on php or functions to alter the current date.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides the filter `get_the_date` that allows to modify the value before it is handled over to the theme or plugin.

This filter is used everytime `get_the_date()` is called.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'modify_get_the_date', 10, 3 );
function modify_get_the_date( $value, $format, $post ) {
    $date = new DateTime( $post->post_date );
    $date->modify( "+100 years" );
    if ( $format == "" )
        $format = get_option( "date_format" );
    return( $date->format( $format ) );
}
```

This function takes the `post_date` from the post, adds the time and returns it according to the format given to `get_the_date()` or with the default format configured in the WordPress options.