# I'm weird with strtotime behaviour

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am getting the From date and To date using jquery datepicker plugin. The following is the output of POST.

```
Array (
    [fromDate] => 01/03/2012
    [toDate] => 15/03/2012
    [hdnDownload] => Download
)
```

I am trying to convert this date format to another date format like this:

```
echo'fromdate'.$fromDate = date("Y/n/j", strtotime($_POST['fromDate']));
echo'todate'.$toDate = date("Y/n/j", strtotime($_POST['toDate']));
```

It gives me the following output:

```
fromdate: 2012-1-3
todate:1969-12-31
```

The fromDate is fine but the ToDate has changed, can you please help me.

Comment: strtotime sometimes exhibits weird behavior.. there are so many date time formats after all. mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, etc. like can you tell me what 05/04/2012 vs 04/05/2012 is? without a format, you cant tell which date im talking about. You might wanna try decompiling your date formats manually if strtotime isn't working well for you such as I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568407/i-want-to-add-100-years-to-the-displayed-wordpress-dates/9568726#9568726

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
php > $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('i/n/Y', '15/03/2012');
php > echo $date->format('Y/n/j');
// 2012/3/11
```

This is useful because you can specify input format. `xx/yy/YY` can be represented either as `i/n/Y` and `n/i/Y` and therefore date is ambiguous => unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to make sure you get correct result is either [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) if you're using PHP >= 5.3.0, or [strptime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) with PHP >= 5.1.0, where you can specify input format.

Although if you still want to allow free format there you might want to make a crutch, that would check with regex for this particular format and use one of these only for american m/d/Y, something like:

```
function parsedate($date) {
    if (preg_match('#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}#', $date)) {
        $parsed = strptime($date, '%m/%d/%Y');
        return mktime(0, 0, 0, $parsed['tm_mon'], $parsed['tm_mday'], 1900+$parsed['tm_year']);
            // 'tm_year' is years since 1900
    } else {
        return strtotime($date);
    }
}
```

It's still a crutch, but I can't see any cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can give unexpected results if the input is invalid or malformed. It would seem that your `$_POST['toDate']` is not valid for `strtotime`to function correctly.

The date you do get is the start date of [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in your timezone.

I would suggest using something other than `strtotime` like the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class or the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

The fromDate is also wrong as you wanted 03 to be the month not 1.

In your case strtotime is thinking the input is Month/Day/Year and as 15 is not a month it messes up.

You could either swap your input strings to

```
[fromDate] => 03/01/2012
[toDate] => 03/15/2012
```

or use createFromFormat in @Vyktor's answer.